# Send voice command to telegram bot using python-telegram-bot Package

Tags: python, bots, python-telegram-bot

I am try to build a telegram bot using python with python-telegram-bot Package and its working with text commands now i try to send a voice command to user ..

my code like

```
def start(update, context):
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.save_to_file('welcome to this bot', 'voice.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()

#return update.message.reply_text('hi i am bot with your friend')
```

the mp3 file is generated , Then how to send that voice file to user any way ?

Comment: ok, this seems like a super basic question regarding the use of the module and I have a feeling that the documentation of the telegram-bot module includes sending voice messages, have You looked at the docs?

Comment: what exactly didn't You understand? here are some docs that You maybe need: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.voice.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're looking for is called `sendVoice` in the [official API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice). for PTB, it's [`Bot.send_voice`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_voice). See also the [`Message.reply_voice`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_voice) shortcut and this [wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media) about working with files in PTB.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.